# How to open ECW file with GDAL in OpenCV 3.0

Tags: c++, opencv, gdal

As you know, GDAL is added to OpenCV version 3. I have a satellite ecw image and want to read and show it. I already try to use OpenCV sample named : gdal-image.cpp. it has a line for reading input image:

```
  cv::Mat image = cv::imread(argv[1], cv::IMREAD_LOAD_GDAL | cv::IMREAD_COLOR );
```

my problem : I set my ecw image as argv[1] but it doesnt work.
 should I convert my image before? 
 any way to read ecw using GDAL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For read ecw image, i suggest you use GDAL, you can download GDAL binary prebuild and ECW extension from here [https://www.gisinternals.com/release.php](https://github.com/marvins/Code_Sandbox/blob/master/c%2B%2B/opencv/geo_tools/gdalToOpenCV.cpp).

For read the first band of image you can use this code:

```
GDALDataset* dataset = (GDALDataset*) GDALOpenEx("image.ecw", GDAL_OF_RASTER, NULL, NULL, NULL);
GDALRasterBand* band = dataset->GetRasterBand(1);

cv::Rect roi(x, y, w, h);

cv::Mat mat;
mat.create(roi.size(),CV_32F);
band->RasterIO( GF_Read, roi.x, roi.y, roi.width, roi.height, mat.data,
                roi.width, roi.height, GDT_Float32, 0, 0);
```

You just have to be sure that OpenCV data type match the GDAL datatype and that ROI dimensions are ok for the raster size. 
For more info it is good: [enter link description here](https://github.com/marvins/Code_Sandbox/blob/master/c%2B%2B/opencv/geo_tools/gdalToOpenCV.cpp)

Answer (score 0):

To read ECW file using GDAL，its driver should be built into the gdal， maybe you should test the supported driver in opencv. If the author didn't add the ecw driver, then do it youself. Here is the page about gdal in OpenCV:http://code.opencv.org/issues/3725

OpenCV's code repository was moved to github, and I can't find this issue, but in github i find something related [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/2806).

Comment: Edit your answer and add the link to **your answer**.